# O que é uma "lista de definição" e como essas tags são usadas <DL>, <DT> e <DD>?

Tags: html, html5, lista

Até onde eu sabia no HTML existiam apenas dois tipos de lista. Listas Ordenadas `<ol><li>` e Lista não ordenada `<ul><li>`. Mas aparentemente existe um terceiro tipo de lista, que é a `Definition List` (lista de definição) `<DL> <DT> e <DD>`

- Como esse tipo de lista deve ser usada? Poderia dar algum exemplo?
- Essa tags tem algum valor semântico diferente dos demais tipos de lista? Existe alguma boa prática para elas?

Comment: Basicamente a tag `<dl>` delimita a lista, a tag `<dt>` define termos e a tag `<dd>` descreve os termos. O [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_dd_test) fornece um link de exemplo a respeito. Daí o nome de "Lista de Definições/Descrições", porque as tags quando utilizadas dessa forma dão uma aparência caracteristica a lista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os elementos `<dl>`, `<dt>` e `<dd>` são usados em conjunto principalmente para:

- Glossários;
- Lista de definições;
- Metadados (conjunto de pares chaves-valor).

Mas a pergunta é: o que significam essas tags HTML?

> O elemento HTML `<dl>` representa uma lista de descrição. O elemento
>   "envolve" uma lista de termos (especifícados pelo elemento `<dt>`) e
>   descrições pelo elemento `<dd>`.

Vou mostrar três exemplos, um para um glossário, um para metadados e para lista de definições.

1. Exemplo para glossário:

```css
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
  <dd>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis mollis est, at porttitor nisi. Curabitur tempor sollicitudin turpis, eget euismod massa accumsan vitae. Vivamus efficitur vitae elit vel luctus. Sed blandit vehicula ultrices.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
  <dd>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis mollis est, at porttitor nisi. Curabitur tempor sollicitudin turpis, eget euismod massa accumsan vitae. Vivamus efficitur vitae elit vel luctus. Sed blandit vehicula ultrices.
  </dd>
  <dt>Lorem ipsum</dt>
  <dd>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis mollis est, at porttitor nisi. Curabitur tempor sollicitudin turpis, eget euismod massa accumsan vitae. Vivamus efficitur vitae elit vel luctus. Sed blandit vehicula ultrices.
  </dd>
</dl>
```

2. Exemplo para lista de definições (com relativa estilização, para facilitar entendimento)

```css
dl.horizontal-definition-list {
    display: table;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.horizontal-definition-list dt, .horizontal-definition-list dd {
    padding: 2% 10%;
}

.horizontal-definition-list dt {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: gold;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.horizontal-definition-list dd {
    display: table-cell;
    background: silver;
}

.horizontal-definition-list dd.line-break {
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<dl class="horizontal-definition-list">
    <dt>Termo 1</dt>
    <dd>Definição 1</dd>
    <dd class="line-break"></dd>
    
    <dt>Termo 2</dt>
    <dd>Definição 2</dd>
    <dd class="line-break"></dd>
    
    <dt>Termo 3</dt>
    <dd>Definição 3<br>(várias linhas, sem problema)</dd>
    <dd class="line-break"></dd>
</dl>
```

3. Exemplo para implementação de lógica para metadados (chave-valor):

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Nome</dt>    
  <dd>João Pedro</dd>
  <dt>Ano</dt>
  <dd>2000</dd>
  <dt>Páis</dt>
  <dd>Brasil</dd>
  <dt>Cor</dt>
  <dd>Vermelho</dd>
</dl>
```

Vale ressaltar que sim, elas possuem valor semântico e são usadas principalmente para os três exemplos que ressaltei aqui. Diferentemente de listas convencionais (sem e com ordenação) as listas de definição (como o próprio nome chama, `<dl>` de Definition List) devem ser usadas em dicionários e definições em geral, até porque, uma `<dl>` não implica uma ordem para o seu conteúdo, mas implica uma semântica sobre os seus elementos filhos.

Em questão de uso para as tags eu acredito que podem ser usadas naquelas linhas do tempo, claro, com certa estilização. Ou também em lista de definições como mostrei no exemplo 3. Mas vejo, na minha opinião, o seu melhor uso em documentações de sistemas, frameworks ou bibliotecas.

*Nota: Jamais use os elementos citados aqui na resposta (`<dl>`, `<dt>` e `<dd>`) para indentar o conteúdo da sua página. Além de ser uma má prática tira o significados dos elementos.*

**Referências:**

- [Documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)
- [Pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414216/when-we-should-use-dl-over-ul)

Comment: Valeu jovem, obrigado pela resposta, está bem completa!